# Why does the term being squared in the Pythagorean triplet make no difference to the whole triplet?

Tags: geometry, arithmetic, square-numbers, pythagorean-triples

I was recently preparing for the SOF IMO Level 2 exam. While practising for the exam, I encountered this question in my textbook about the chapter **Square and Square Roots** which also mentions the Pythagorean Triplets. This is the question:

$$22^2 + (m^2 - 1)^2 = 122^2$$

where we have to find the value of m. We could do it manually but there is an optimised solution given in the book I was unable to understand. This is exactly what the book says:

> We have, $22^2 + (m^2 - 1)^2 = 122^2$
>
> or $(11 \times 2)^2 + (m^2 - 1)^2 = (11^2 +1)^2$
>
> Since, $2m$, $m^2 - 1$ and $m^2 + 1$ forms a Pythagorean Triplet,
>
> So, we have m = 11

If the question were not having squares on every term, it would indeed be solvable via the triplet formula. But, since the square was added to every term, this does not feel right.

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: What's the question?  If you are concerned that $11$ might not work, you could simply try it.  Of course $m=-11$ would also work, but I'm guessing that the problem specified $m\in \mathbb N$.  Otherwise, what are you asking?

Comment: Worth remarking:  Setting $M=m^2-1$  your equation is just $M^2=122^2-22^2$.

Comment: @lulu I know it works. But why does squaring every term keep the equation equal?

Comment: They are applying the general form of a pythagorean triplet $ \{ 2ab, a^2 - b^2 , a^2 + b^2 \}$, and observing that $ a = 11, b = 1$ fits.

Comment: I don't understand.  It isn't true that $2m+m^2-1=m^2+1$ if that's what you are asking....Pythagorean triples are $(a,b,c)$ with $a^2+b^2=c^2$.  Here, the triple is $(2m, m^2-1, m^2+1)$.

Comment: The point of the question is to get you to recognize/use the identity $(x+1)^2=(x-1)^2+4x$, which is a specific form of $(r+s)^2-(r-s)^2=4rs$.

Comment: Yeah, I get it now. @RobinSparrow. I am currently in grade 8 and am just introduced to identities. I had not known about this one yet. But that's for the information :)

Comment: @Sambhav Kahandelwal, it's a useful identity. Turn it around: if  is a natural number, i.e., =, you have  is the difference of two (rational) squares. If $v=4rs$ then you have a $v$ is expressible as a difference of perfect squares.

Comment: @lulu is getting at the point (+1!). The triple itself doesn't have the squares, but it satisfies an equation in which the members of the triple are squared. Distinguish carefully between the **Pythagorean triple** and the **condition it satisfies** in order to be a Pythagorean triple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that no matter what $m$ is, it is always true that $$(2m)^2 + (m^2-1)^2 = \underbrace{4m^2}_{(2m)^2} + \underbrace{m^4 -2m^2 + 1}_{(m^2-1)^2}\tag{clear parentheses}$$
$$=m^4 + 2m^2 + 1\tag{combine like terms}$$
$$ = (m^2 + 1)^2\tag{recognize perfect square trinomial}$$
That is, for any $m$ it is true that $(2m)^2 + (m^2-1)^2=(m^2+1)^2$.

Now, saying $$``a, b, \textrm{ and } c \textrm{ form a Pythagorean triple" (note no squares)}$$ means exactly $$``a^2 + b^2 = c^2" \;\;\; \textrm{(note squares).}$$

The "shortcut" is just saying that you can notice that taking $m=11$ produces the correct value for the $(2m)^2$ and $(m^2+1)^2$ terms, so the third term must match as well:
$$(m^2 - 1)^2 = (11^2 - 1)^2$$
from which you may "observe" that $m=11$.

Note that this assumes $m$ is a nonnegative real number. There are other solutions if that assumption isn't made:
$$(m^2 - 1)^2 = 120^2$$
$$m^2 - 1 = \pm 120$$
$$m^2 = 1 \pm 120$$
$$m^2 = 121 \;\;\; \textrm{or}\;\;\; m^2 = -119$$
$$m = 11, \;\;\; \textrm{or}\;\;\; m = -11, \;\;\; \textrm{or}\;\;\; m = i\sqrt{119}, \;\;\; \textrm{or}\;\;\; m = -i\sqrt{119}$$

Comment: I feel I have found a relation. Its for the sides of a right triangle. $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ where a and b are legs and c is hypotenuse. Am I right?

Comment: While your statements are correct, I don't think it addresses the issue that OP brought up. They are not asking for how to solve the problem. They are asking how to understand/interpret/create the given solution.

Comment: @CalvinLin : As I said, it is simply "noticing" that $11$ is involved since $22$ and $122$ appear. Surely $22$ suggests $11$, and then you would surely notice that $122$ is only one more than $121$. Having seen this "trick" once, it will likely be in one's toolbox from then on, no?

Comment: My point is that the solution didn't start off with "Let's prove that $(2m)^2 + (m^2 -1)^2 = (m^2 + 1 ) ^2$", but is instead applying the general form of a pythagorean triplet. $\quad$ Though, given that OP is " in grade 8 and am just introduced to identities", they likely don't comprehend this distinction.